# How to find the list of custom post type where logged in user is author

Tags: plugins, themes

I need to find a list of custom posts where the logged in user is the author of the post

Comment: Please try this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56410/137328

Comment: @GufranHasan That question doesn't have anything to do with Pratikb's. They're asking about getting posts by author, not role.

Comment: @pratikb-simform Did you try anything? If you could paste some sort of code you might have tried.

Comment: I have used this code so far but no success

$author_query_id= array('post_author' => $userID, 'post_type'=>'estate_agent');
$author_posts_id = new WP_Query($author_query_id);

It shows all posts not with the author id given

Comment: Are you defining $userID anywhere?

Comment: Yes it is defined and I am getting proper value for it also. 
` $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $userID                         =   $current_user->ID;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for it and here is it

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$userID       = $current_user->ID;

  $args =array( 'author' => $userID,'post_type' => 'custom_post' ) ;
  $authors_posts = get_posts($args);


    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $content= $authors_post->post_title;
    }

echo $content;
```